# What is the meaning of this words: "And all Captain Nemo's for the taking."?

Tags: meaning

In ***[20,000 Leagues Under the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20,000_Leagues_Under_the_Sea_(1954_film))***, Professor Pierre Aronnax narrate This lines:

> Necessary to sustain life. An underwater larder filled to overflowing,
>   and **all Captain Nemo's for the taking**.

**for the taking** what exactly? I was confused how to understand this above lines?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the phrase **for the taking**? See [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for_the_taking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possessive + **for the taking** is an idiom that means "freely available {to you|him|her|them|us}".

> I'm getting a new tennis racket. My old one is *yours for the taking*, if
>   you want it.

P.S. Don't be misled, by online sources which cite the *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms*, into thinking that this is an AmE idiom only. It is also used in BrE.